# Yarn - timezone setting for now()

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

My application jar is on yarn-cluster and it executes sql query to other db server. It works well but when I insert time data as 'now()'. It does not follow its system timezone nor db server timezone. I think It's somehow following yarn or hadoop timezone, but don't know how to set it. I tried like below but not work.

in mapred-size.xml

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Duser.timezone=KST</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapred.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Duser.timezone=KST</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Duser.timezone=KST</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Im having a similar problem, were you able to resolve it by any chance?

Comment: @Felix I queried with timezone like 'now() AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Seoul''